# Java Applets on iOS

Tags: java, ios, mobile, applet, oracle-adf

I know the two hate each other, but I have done some research on using Oracle ADF Mobile to run Java on an iOS device. I'm trying to develop a way to run a Java applet inside an iOS app. The demos and tutorials I have seen have been less than useful in achieving this, and I'm stuck.

Does anyone know if this is possible, has been done, or maybe an open source sample I can look at to help?

Comment: There is no JVM for iOS (at least I know there isn't in a non-jailbroken environment).

Comment: One of the problems with allowing applets on a system meant for mobile usage (small screen) is that some typical desktop components such as trees are not workable on the small screen.

Comment: I'd mainly want the app to work on iPad, so I'm not extremely concerned about the small screen. At this point, I'm just trying to get a Java applet to load somehow in iOS. I can deal with the other aspects once I get that working (again, if it is possible)

Comment: *"(again, if it is possible)"*  Seems from @rmaddy that you first need to write a JVM..

Comment: That's why I was trying to use the ADF (idea sparked from http://www.zdnet.com/oracle-puts-java-apps-on-ipads-and-iphones-7000006209/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it'll work, but you can try add an applet to the amx file in ADF Mobile, and see if hows up, because the VM that oracle put on the iOS is really different from the one that is required for the applet to run effectively!!!